# Parse XML to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parsing, afnetworking

I was using AFNetworking 1.4.3 to retrieve `NSDictionary` from JSON. Now I have to use new AFNetworking 2.0 to parse XML file. For example:

```
    [self getPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *responseObject) {
        // Mapping XML to my own MR_object
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // Error handling here
    }];
```

Is it possible to map XML file directly to `NSDictionary` without using `NSXMLParser`? I am looking for equvalent for this for in 2.0 and for XML input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can avoid nsxmlparser. use libxml directly which is the C api that powers the NSXMLParser.

### working code

Nice working code from apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html
**Not ONLY libxml but also show the usage of libxml**

### Tutorial

A nice article that explains how to use livxml:
http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

---

### idea 1

if you are looking for ready-made code then nicklockwood's XMLDictionary class looks like a very good fit:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary
**It Internally uses NSXMLParser though**

### idea 2

if you have a XSD File for your xml, check out my project xsd2cocoa:
https://github.com/Daij-Djan/xsd2cocoa
**No NSXMLParser at all**