# How to store a XML from a url to a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

I am searching in the whole internet on how can I store my xml data to a NSDictionary, but it seems that I can't find a solution that will fix my problem. I need to store my data into a NSDictionary, the data comes from xml stored in a url. Is there a algorithm on how to do it? Without using any 3rd party program if possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML to NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553557/parse-xml-to-nsdictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSXMLParser`:

```
NSURL *yoururl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Enter your URL here"]];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:yoururl];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict
{
    //Use attributeDict to get parsed XML into NSDictionary
}
```

And for more info see this:

[Xml parsing in iOS tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial)

I hope this will help you..:)

Comment: Is it normal to have \t and \n in the text of my xml? I am able to parse it and here's a sample text = "\n\t\t\n\t\t\tCheck";

Comment: see this bro : https://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project  OR.. https://github.com/71squared/TBXML